# How to retrieve the dates of entries not present in database?

Tags: php, algorithm

The question is self explanatory...

What i did however to do this is as follows

I managed to get the data from database .. I managed to create a list of all dates in a month, now I am trying to cross check them ..

Information in the database as loaded in the array $dsr

PS: I don't know how to show data from database mysql here so I am using array to show it here

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [dsr_date] => 2020-05-01
            [toolplaza_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [dsr_date] => 2020-05-02
            [toolplaza_id] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [dsr_date] => 2020-05-03
            [toolplaza_id] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [dsr_date] => 2020-05-04
            [toolplaza_id] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [status] => 2
            [dsr_date] => 2020-05-05
            [toolplaza_id] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [dsr_date] => 2020-05-06
            [toolplaza_id] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [dsr_date] => 2020-05-07
            [toolplaza_id] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [dsr_date] => 2020-05-08
            [toolplaza_id] => 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [dsr_date] => 2020-05-09
            [toolplaza_id] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [status] => 2
            [dsr_date] => 2020-05-10
            [toolplaza_id] => 1
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [status] => 0
            [dsr_date] => 2020-05-13
            [toolplaza_id] => 1
        )

)
```

Code to get all dates of month

```
$today_date = date('Y-m-d');
$start_date = date('Y-m').'-01';
/*$start_date = $year."-".$month."-01";*/
$start_time = strtotime($start_date);

$end_time = strtotime($today_date) + 86400;

for($i=$start_time; $i<$end_time; $i+=86400)
{
   $list[] = date('Y-m-d', $i);
}
```

Code to cross check

```
$days = 0;
foreach($list as $date){
    if(empty($dsr[$days])){
        $missing_days[] = date("j F Y", strtotime($date));
    }
    if(isset($dsr[$days])){
        $nu = 0;
        foreach($dsr as $dsrs){
            if($dsrs['dsr_date'] == $date){
                if($dsrs['status'] == 2){
                    $rejected[] = date("j F Y", strtotime($list[$days]));
                }
                if($dsrs['status'] == 1){
                    $approved[] = date("j F Y", strtotime($list[$days]));
                }
                if($dsrs['status'] == 0){
                    $pending[] = date("j F Y", strtotime($list[$days]));
                }
                $nu++;
            }

        }
    }
    $days++;
}
```

As you can see from the data of database, I have an entry of date 2020-05-13 with an index of 10 .. my algorithm cross check the indexes, and as there are 10 indexes, and 13th index does not contain any value .. it shows that dsr of 13th date in the missing array .. which i don't want ?
What would be the best algorithm to do this .. as mine failed ..

Comment: First of all - _don’t_ work with `86400`, not every day is exactly that long. `strtotime` supports syntax like `+1 day`, so use that.

Comment: Secondly, your data array has only one entry for each date, right? Then I would transform this to an array that uses the date value as key - then you can easily check if an entry for a given date exists, simply by using `isset` or `array_key_exists`.

Comment: Fair point .. I tested your method to work for those days where there are only single entries .. but its gonna create a mess when there are a number of entries for each date

Comment: Doing anything based on the _index_ of your data array does not make sense to begin with them. Determining the “missing days” would need to happen inside the loop over all records then, because only in there you will know which dates actually exist.

Comment: Maybe easier to determine the missing days outside of any loops. Use `array_column` to get an array that contains only the date values from your input array, and then use `array_diff` to determine which entries in `$list` are missing.

Comment: Good approach, thank you CBroe

Comment: Create object with the begin and end date with the dates as index and set them all to false, check the ones found and you have your list